# Formatting a date in Oracle to show month and day

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-format

I have the date as below

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDD') FROM dual;
```

result for above query is : `117`

I need to convert this **117** to **month and day**. anyone knows how to perform this in PL SQL

**the expected result is 04-27**

Answer (score 2):

Change `'DDD'` to `'MM-DD'`.

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD') 
FROM dual;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
04-27
```

**Demo:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/622055/7

**EDITED:**

`DDD` shows Number of Days from the first of a year.

For Example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'DDD') 
FROM dual;
```

gives output `001` since it is the First Day of year `2018`.

So to break `117` you need the year.
Then you can use this query.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + column_name - 1, 'MM-DD') 
FROM dual;
```

**Example Query:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + 117 - 1, 'MM-DD')
FROM dual;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
04-27
```

**Demo:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/622055/37

Comment: thanks  for the answer. another issue I am facing the DB column has the values as 117 so I need to brake this 117 into MM-DD. any idea how to do that ?

Comment: ok thanks this worked. How do I convert this to date 770719 the expected outcome is 1977-07-19 any oracle function for this

Comment: @user2134292 If you find this answer useful please accept it as the answer

Comment: @user2134292 Ya there is a function `TO_DATE` but it is giving above date `770719` as `2077-07-19` since it doesn't know from the string whether it is `1977` or `2077`

Comment: @user2134292 If you find the answer useful please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "117" and want to convert it to a date, you'll have to use a little bit (but really - just a little bit) of arithmetics. As 'DDD' represents number of days since the 1st of current year, add it to ... well *the 1st of current year* and apply appropriate format mask to convert it to date. I subtracted "1" as you want to get *yesterday*.

For example:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'ddd') from dual;

TO_
---
117

SQL> select to_date(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + 117, 'dd.mm.rrrr') - 1 resul
  2  from dual;

RESULT
----------
27.04.2018

SQL>
```

Or, using the format you specified (MM-DD):

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + 117 - 1, 'mm-dd') result
  2  from dual;

RESUL
-----
04-27

SQL>
```